# How to regain the memory used by MDIChild (while close the same)?

Tags: .net, winforms

I am using VS 4.0, I have MenuMDI parent form which is responsible for opening the child forms via MenuStrip.

Each menu strip click event, will create the form instance of the child form and set the MDI parent to the Main-MenuMDI form.

Every thing works fine. There is a memory takes while open the child-form. but this memory is not regain after closing from the MenuMDI.

Comment: For debugging purpose use `GC.Collect` and check if that's just a matter of GC which didn't happened yet. Otherwise, Use a memory profiler.

Comment: @vaduganathan Are those child forms disposed properly after closing?

Comment: @ Siva Gopal How do I dispose the child form while it close?

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution in C#.

```
    CHILD_Form newForm = new CHILD_Form();

    newForm.ShowDialog();

    newForm.Dispose();
```

In C++ simply delete the cfild form

```
delete newForm
```

Onother thing in C++ is: if you are allocating sometning with the child form (such as arrays or stream) you have to delete them on closing event of the child form.

**From MSDN**

When a form is closed, all resources created within the object are closed and the form is disposed. You can prevent the closing of a form at run time by handling the Closing event and setting the Cancel property of the CancelEventArgs passed as a parameter to your event handler. If the form you are closing is the startup form of your application, your application ends.
The two conditions when a form is not disposed on Close is when (1) it is part of a multiple-document interface (MDI) application, and the form is not visible; and (2) you have displayed the form using ShowDialog. In these cases, you will need to call Dispose manually to mark all of the form's controls for garbage collection.

Comment: It is easy to close the object and dispose the same in same method. Acutally in my case one dedicated method to create form instance and add it to MDIChild. While close the form how can I identify the form being closed?

Comment: Are you using ShowDialog method to show your child form? Are you allocating dynamically something in the child form? Add your code to the question.

Comment: 'Priate Sub AddForm()
   Dim NewFormInstance as New Form1()
   NewFormInstance.MdiParent = Me
   NewFormInstance.Show()
End Sub'
This is what the code inside the method to create a new instance and add the same to the MDI.

Comment: In that way the Close method dispose automatically the form. What is not disposed are all the stuff you allocate whithin the Child form (arrays, streams, etc..). On close event of child form you have to be sure that all memory is released.

Comment: Yes, We can do on_closing event of the each child forms. Currently it is not feasible solution to achieve. My project have numerous child forms. Is there generic way to identify the form being closed in MenuMDI and dispose that form object directly?

Comment: I think the best way is to define your own MDIChild form type that implements the on_closing event, and substituite it as the tpe of your Child forms. Another way is to have a Task or a timer that look continuously to all form in this.MdiChildren and if the Visible property is set to false, Dispose it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68802/discussion-between-vaduganathan-and-lps).